# Tomcat 7 maxSpareThreads ,liveDeploy ,debug

Tags: tomcat7

The following warnings are reported when I start Tomcat 7:

> Jan 20, 2011 8:27:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
> WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} **Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '75' did not find a matching property.**
>
> Jan 20, 2011 8:27:50 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} **Setting property 'liveDeploy' to 'false' did not find a matching property.**
>
> Jan 20, 2011 8:27:50 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} **Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.**

Why are these warnings being reported? The properties mentioned are specified in the `server.xml` file, which was created for Tomcat 5.5.

I want to know what are the alternatives in Tomcat 7. Should I just remove these parameters from server.xml or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 10):

the maxSpareThreads configuration parameter was removed in tomcat 6, so it's no longer valid/applicable.  see the tomcat 5 documentation pages for the configuration element in question: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html
 (maxSpareThreads is present), 
and absent in the corresponding tomcat 6 documentation page.