# Why number of threads show in JMX does not match the tomcat settings?

Tags: tomcat, jvm, java, jmx

My tomcat settings:

```
maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
```

According to JMX, my current busy thread is 3

```
currentThreadsBusy = 3
```

But

```
currentThreadCount= 100
```

Why it used up all my threads? Shouldn't the current thread be something like `78` (75+3)?

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Tomcat that has a maxSpareThreads parameter is 5.5. You should have warnings in your logs, as described here: [Tomcat 7 maxSpareThreads ,liveDeploy ,debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756918/tomcat-7-maxsparethreads-livedeploy-debug)